# Skype install error ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, skype

Trying to install Skype using [this ubuntuhandbook.org guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-skype-4-3-in-ubuntu-16-04/)

I get this error on running reload cache (step 2 1st part):

```
W: GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
W: The repository 'https:repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @karel E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
this is the error i get if i try it

Comment: Unlock the locked administration directory with these answers: [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process) and then you will be ready to install Skype.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ok. Understood.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Skype 4.3 won't do you any good, even if you could install it. Microsoft has stopped supporting it, and effective July 1 2017, you won't even be able to log in. They want you to use the newer Skype 5.3.0.1. And, you'll be disappointed in Skype 5.3.0.1 as it's missing a whole bunch of features that were in Skype 4.3, or in the Windows version.

Get the newest version at https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/